# How to get values in an array using another array with the indexes of the values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have an array of floats (size 9300), and another array of ints (size 2600) with indexes of the first array. I am trying to get the values in the first array based on the index in the second array. Example:

```
index   1st_array
0       12.00
1       3.89 
2       24.20
3       34.60

index  2nd_array
0       0
1       2
```

The output:

```
index      3nd_array
0          12.00
1          24.20
```

Edit: those are actually numpy arrays:

```
a1 = np.array([12.00, 3.89, 24.20, 34.60])
a2 = np.array([0, 2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two Series `s1` and `s2`, use:

```
s1.loc[s2]
```

Example:

```
s1 = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
s2 = pd.Series([0, 2])

s1.loc[s2]
0    a
2    c
dtype: object
```

For numpy arrays

```
a1[a2]
```

Example:

```
a1 = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
a2 = np.array([0, 2])

a1[a2]
array(['a', 'c'], dtype='<U1')
```

For DataFrames:

```
df1.set_index('index').loc[df2['2nd_array']].reset_index()
```

*NB. the `set_index`/`reset_index` are only required if "index" are columns*

Example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'index': [0, 1, 2, 3], 
                    '1st_array': [12.0, 3.89, 24.2, 34.6]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'index': [0, 1],
                    '2nd_array': [0, 2]})

(df1
 .set_index('index')
 .loc[df2['2nd_array']]
 .reset_index()
 )

   index  1st_array
0      0       12.0
1      2       24.2
```

Comment: @Fred so which case did you have?

Comment: For numpy arrays, but the one for dataframe end up being useful for something else as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([12.00, 3.89, 24.20, 34.60])
arr2 = np.array([0, 2])
print(arr1[arr2])
```

prints

```
[12.  24.2]
```